# Dagger 2 instantiation on application component

Tags: java, android, dagger

I have a question with dagger2,

If I provide `@Singleton` with ApplicationComponent but don't instantiate the object using `@Inject` in some class. Does the object get instantiate or it will get instantiated when it is `@Inject` in some class? 
For example, in below code, does test instantiated on main2?

```
@Singleton
public class Test {
    @Inject
    public Test() {
    }
}


public class main() {

    @Inject Test test;

    public void start() {
        DaggerComponent.create().inject(this);
    }
}

public class main2() {
    public void start() {
        DaggerComponent.create().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get instantiated when it is injected in some class.

You can check the generated code by dagger for the `inject(main2)` method for your `DaggerComponent` class and it will be empty like this:

```
   @Override
     public void inject(main2 clazz) {}
```

Whereas the `inject(main)` method will have calls to inject the field (after creating an instance of it).

Answer (score 2):

In above case , Test will be instantiated in class Main by the instance of the DaggerComponent in that class .

But in class Main2 , Test will not be instanciated unless an explicit @Inject annotation is marked on a property of type Test .

Also , note that in case above , if you need singleton instance of class Test in both class Main and Main2 , use the same DaggerComponent instance to inject Test object in both class . As you are separately instanciating DaggerComponent in both classes , you will get separate instances of class Test in Main and Main2.

If you want to know how dagger uses scopes behind the scenes, read the Dagger generated code   . I have written an article on medium regarding  how dagger scopes works internally. Follow this if you want to . [How Dagger scopes work internally](https://medium.com/@er.abhishek.luthra/dagger-2-scopes-unriddled-f5c3f2f2dff2)

Comment: You **must** [disclose your affiliation with links!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)